# Ajax give back the code HTML of the recent page, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

Really is very simple my code, and I worked many times with ajax without problems. But now I've this:

```
var dataForm=jQuery('form').serialize();
jQuery.post(  
        '/home/index/page/1', 
        dataForm,
        process_Results_Search 
        ); 

function process_Results_Search(response)
        {
                console.log('Im processing data');
                console.log(response);
        }
```

In my controller I only make a simple echo:

```
echo "im here";
```

But my response is something like this (content of the recent page). I'M USING ZEND:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    ....

im here<!----------in the end of the response!!!---------------->
```

Comment: What do you get when you see the response of the POST in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

OK, fixed. I was sending the post to the same view that I was using to render the page with the form. SO I was rendering again the same view. I needed to create a different action to process the request ajax

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to disable template on your response view!

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use a different action.  In my code, I have some pages that use basically the same code for AJAX calls and regular calls (popup windows for example).  You can check if the call is an ajax one and disable the layout and view if that is the case:

```
    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    }
```